# innerHTMLで挿入されたテキストをクローラーが認識しない

Tags: javascript

javascriptで、innerHTMLを使ってクイズアプリを作ったのですが、innerHTMLで挿入されるテキストをグーグルのクローラーが認識しないと聞きます。
それによってSEO上上位表示しなかったり、同じ型を使って、クイズの中身だけ変更して量産すると重複コンテンツと判断されて、全く評価がされない問題が起きてしまいます。

複数同じ型のクイズアプリを作っても重複コンテンツと思われずに、問などを認識させるためには、HTMLにも同じ内容を記載して、display:none;で消すか、回答はかけないのでせめて、問だけは、ズラッとHTMLに記載して、消さずにこんな問題がありますよと、表記させて、閲覧者にも意味があるように持っていくしかないかなと思ってますが、他にinnerHTMLで問などを入れていく現状でうまく認識させる方法はないでしょうか？

問だけは、ズラッとHTMLに記載する方法はすぐにできるのですがinnerHTMLに問いがあるので、これをひとつづつコピペしていくのが、数が多いためちょっと大変です。
もっと妙案があれば教えてください。

Comment: nicomesecond さん、何をクローラーが認識しないのかの部分が消えているようです。アプリそのものが認識されないということでしょうか。修正お願いできますでしょうか？

Comment: WEBアプリの存在は認識しますが、innerHTMLで挿入されるテキストを一切認識しないということです。

Comment: Javascriptがタグとしてあるので少しお門違いですが、PHPなどサーバサイドで問題を出力することをオススメします。そうでなければ固定値で最初からHTMLに埋め込むしかないです。

Comment: 問題出題ボタンを押した際にDOM生成して問題が作られるのですがこれをjsでやっている現在の形からphpで実行してやるだけでクローラーは認識できるということでしょうか？ページを読み込み時には存在しないことに変わりはないですが結果は違うのですね。

Comment: ＞＞＞
問だけは、ズラッとHTMLに記載する方法はすぐにできるのですがinnerHTMLに問いがあるので、これをひとつづつコピペしていくのが、数が多いためちょっと大変です。

やはりこの方法が一番よさそうですね。js、htmlに問題文を二度書きするのは大変ですが、

Comment: それか、問題回答をすべてhtmlに記載して、display:none;で隠しておいて、すべてポジションで重ねて出題ボタンを押すとひとつづつ問題が見えるようになるようにするしかないですね。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Googleのbotは、JavaScriptで記述したページを認識することができます。

参考 [Deprecating our AJAX crawling scheme](https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2015/10/deprecating-our-ajax-crawling-scheme.html)

最近のgoogleは、`Progressive Web App`に力を入れていますが、`Progressive Web App`というのはまさに`HTML+Javascript`で作ったサイトです。

ただし、`JavaScript`で作成したwebサイトをgoogleに認識してもらう場合には少し注意が必要です。まず、googleのbotがボタンを押したりフォームに入力をしてくれるわけではないので、urlを使ってアクセスしてきて、それで表示されるページしか認識されません。

したがって、現状だとGoogleのbotからは1ページしかないWebサイトに見えてしまいます。それで、各質問ごとにurlを設定した方がいいでしょう。urlの設定には、例えば上に書いた参考のブログにもある`History API pushState()`が使えます。pushStateを使えば、ページ遷移をしないでもアドレスバーのurlを書き換えることができ、ブラウザーの履歴機能を使うことができるようになります。

```
var stateObj = { foo: "bar" };
history.pushState(stateObj, "page 2", "bar.html");
```

すでにinnerHTMLを使ってクイズを表示しているのであれば、その場所にhistory.pushStateを追加だけなのでそれほど大きな修正にはならないでしょう。そうしてしまえば、PHPのようなサーバーサイドレンダリングを使ってhtml全体を書き換えるよりも画面表示の更新がずっと速くできます。それこそ、googleが`Progressive Web App`を押している理由の一つです。

やり方を簡単に説明すると、質問と回答を、HTMLに書いておく、jsファイルに書く、独立したjsonする、のいずれの方法でもできます。例えば、jsファイルに書くのであれば、次のような連想配列を作っておきます。

```
var qa = {
    'q1':{
        'q': '質問1',
        'a': '回答1',
    },
    'q2':{
        'q': '質問2',
        'a': '回答2',
    },
    .......          
}
```

初期画面（例えば`a.html`）だと、`for (quesion in qa)`で連想配列を順番に取得できるので、質問だけを並べればいいでしょう。
また、個別の質問を表示するページのurlを`a.html?q=q1`というようなクエリー形式にするのであれば、次のようにしてクエリーを取得できるので、urlにクエリーがある場合は該当の質問と回答を表示するようにすればいいです。

```
var url = window.location.pathname;
var query = url.split('?')[1];
```

参考になる資料: Googleの「[はじめてのプログレッシブ ウェブアプリ](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/codelabs/your-first-pwapp/?hl=ja)」
また、`Vue.js`がこういう考え方でWebサイトを作成するフレームワークなので、`Vue.js`を勉強するもいいと思います。

Comment: とても参考になります。ただ問題数分ページを作らないといけないということですか？1ページクローラー用のページを作って、こんな内容がこのクイズにはあるんだよ。
だからこの内容があるという形で大本のページを評価してねとはできないのですか？
そうでないとクイズのページは評価されずクイズの回答のページのみが評価されることになりませんか？
それならクイズのページに問題文だけズラッとかくしかないかなと思っています。

Comment: 調べてみました。
history.pushState(null, 'なんでもOKただの名前', 'ja.stackoverflow.com/a.html');
アドレスがhttps://ja.stackoverflow.com/ja.stackoverflow.com/a.html
と変更されるが、ここに移動するわけではないのですね。
実際にa.htmlが存在してここに回答問題解説が記載してあればページ遷移しないでこの内容がページ全体に表記されるのでしょうか？
それともiframeのように一部だけ変更できるのですか？
いまいちイメージできません。
ただ、a.htmlにすべての回答を記載してしまうと問題をひとつ解くと他の回答まで見えてしまいませんか？
そのために100問あったら100ページ個別に作らないといけないということでしょうか？

Comment: <=この趣旨を工夫してページに記載すれば良いと思います。クイズの概要や種類などを日本語で説明すれば、利用者もグーグルもわかってくれると思います。
<=どのようにすればわかってもらえるのでしょうか？現在思いつくのは、クイズ本体のページに、問題一覧のみをすらっと並べる方法です。回答と解説は評価してもらえませんが。
別ページにクローラーだけ認識できるページを作って本体のページのないようとして認識してもらうことはできるのですか？

Comment: クローラーだけ認識できるページを作るというのはクローキングというGoogle のガイドラインに違反する行為になります。JavaScriptだけでWebサイトを作ることは難しくないし、ユーザーエクスペリエンスを高める手段です。しかし、日本ではやっている人が少なく日本語の資料は少ない上に間違ったものもあるという状況です。WebとJavaScriptをもう少し学習しましょう。

Comment: <=この趣旨を工夫してページに記載すれば良いと思います。クイズの概要や種類などを日本語で説明すれば、利用者もグーグルもわかってくれると思います。 <=どのようにすればわかってもらえるのでしょうか？現在思いつくのは、クイズ本体のページに、問題一覧のみをすらっと並べる方法です。回答と解説は評価してもらえませんが。
こちらを教えてもらえませんか。

Comment: 具体的にどのようにすれば、「クイズの概要や種類などを日本語で説明すれば、利用者もグーグルもわかってくれると思います。」このようにできるのですか？

Comment: お返事どうも。タイピングのサイトも、テキスト情報がほとんどありませんが、テキスト情報がなければだめなのではなく、タイピングを1ページにせずに複数ページにして、
種類ごとに分ければ、テキスト情報がなくても評価されるということですか？
とりあえず問題文をクイズのページにすべてズラッと並べてみました。これで少なくても問題文だけは認識できるので、違う問題がズラッとあればそれぞれのページは別の内容なんだなと思いますよね。
ただ、クイズまとめのようなページは、それぞれの問題を集めただけなので、やはり重複コンテンツと思われるでしょうね。
これはどうしようもないかな？

Answer (score 2):

> javascriptで、innerHTMLを使ってクイズアプリを作ったのですが、クイズアプリをグーグルのクローラーが認識しないと聞きます。

直接確認されたのでしょうか？ Googleはサイト管理者向けに[Search Console](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/home?hl=ja)というツールを提供し、サイトがGoogleによってどのように解釈されたかの情報を提供しています。
また、[検索エンジン最適化（SEO）スターター ガイド](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/7451184?hl=ja)や[ウェブマスター向けガイドライン（品質に関するガイドライン）](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/35769)も提供していますので、これらを踏まえてサイトを設計することをお勧めします。

例えば

> サイトの重要なコンテンツをデフォルトで表示します。Google はタブや展開するセクションなどのナビゲーション要素内に含まれる非表示の HTML コンテンツをクロールできますが、こうしたコンテンツはユーザーがアクセスしにくいものとみなされ、また、最も重要な情報はページの表示時にデフォルトで閲覧可能となっているものと解釈されます。

と説明されています。クイズ１問１問にアクセス可能なURLが用意されないことには、キーワードとして解釈されません。（逆にキーワードとして解釈されたとして検索結果に表示されるようになったとして、閲覧者がアクセスしても当該クイズ問題が表示されない場合、閲覧者はGoogleの検索精度が低いと判断しますよね？）

---

> その問題がすぐに出るかわわかりませんが、進めていくうちに必ず出てきますが、それでもだめなのですか
>
> 別ページにクローラーだけ認識できるページを作って本体のページのないようとして認識してもらうことはできるのですか？

本意でないと思いたいですが、これらの発言だけを見ると訪問者やクローラーを騙すことが目的になっているように思えてなりません。もう一度、ウェブマスター向けガイドライン（品質に関するガイドライン）から引用します。

> #### 基本方針
>
> - 検索エンジンではなく、ユーザーの利便性を最優先に考慮してページを作成する。
> - ユーザーをだますようなことをしない。
> - 検索エンジンでの掲載位置を上げるための不正行為をしない。

サイトの目的を見失うべきではなく、閲覧者のためのサイト作りをしてください。

Comment: その問題がすぐに出るかわわかりませんが、進めていくうちに必ず出てきますが、それでもだめなのですか＞

Comment: @nicomesecond それを判断するのはあなたでも私でもなく閲覧者です。クイズ問題文からクイズサイトにジャンプしたいと考える閲覧者がどれほどいるか（検索結果からクリックされるか）、です。そして閲覧者の意図を汲み取ったGoogleが検索結果に反映します。

Answer (score 0):

説明しずらいので回答に書きます。
具体的には、別ページとしてクロールされる様にjavascriptで作るページのURLは以下の様になります。

http://hoge.jp/calendar/index.html?ym=201806&day=6
　http://hoge.jp/calendar/index.html?ym=201807&day=11

SEOを意識している様なので知っていると思うのでが、これから初めてホームページを作りGoogleで検索できる様にする人の為に基本の基本を

・title、metaをページ毎に重複しない様に設定（スクリプトで設定してしても良い）

```
例、

<title>クイズページのタイトル</title>
<meta name="keywords" content="クイズ,quiz">
<meta name="description" content="クイズページの概要説明する文">
```

・hタグを適切に使う

```
 <h1>クイズページのタイトル</h1>
　　<h2>見出し１</h2>
　　<h2>見出し２</h2>
```

・全ページクロール（見てもらう為に）全ページにメニューリンクを作る。（あくまでも見に来てくれた人の為になる様によく見える所に設置する）

・見に来てくれた人に有益な情報をもたらす内容になる様に心がける。

Comment: 例えば、TCP、リナックス、ウィンドウズのクイズアプリを作った場合、猿でもわかる無料TCPアプリ、猿でもわかる無料リナックスアプリとどうしても同じになってしまいませんか？
これがCTRが高くても、無理やり違うタイトルにしないと重複コンテンツと思われるということでしょうか？
また、別ページとしてクロールされる様にとは、回答などは別ページの一つにまとめてそれをつかって回答を表記するということでしょうか？もう少し具体的ン教えていただければ幸いです。